# Multiple table row name attribute to json array

Tags: html, node.js, express

In express, when I do a post from a form:

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="remarks"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="remarks"></td>
</tr>
```

`var body = req.body;`, body give me this:

```
{ name: [ 'Tel', 'Tel2' ], remarks ['test1','test2'] }
```

How can I get this in json array:

```
{debtor: [{name:'Tel', remarks:'test1'}, {name:'Tel2', remarks:'test2'} ]
```

If the remarks `test1 is empty`, I wont be able to know test2 is belong to row 1 or row2.

Comment: What is your current code?

Comment: @dfsq var body = req.body;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just transform the req.body object as you wish.

```
var body = [];
for(var n=0; n<req.body.name.length; n++){
  body.push({name : req.body.name[n], remarks : req.body.remarks[n]});
}
```

Comment: The problem is when the first row remarks might be empty, so from the code, it won't be able to identity the remarks is from first or second row.

Comment: make it an empty string on validation when the user doesn't fill the remarks.